# PHP with MySQL returns correct result only for first row of Table

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently gotten a PHP script i've written to return data back to my android java code, Unfortunately the script will only return data when I make a call to the first row of my table.

My Table is formatted as such:

```
1 Jared Jones
2 Karla Cross
3 Jasmine Smith
4 Vince Stevens
```

The numbers correspond to a UserId and the other 2 attributes are FName and LName.

My php script to execute the MySQL script is as follows:

```
    <?php 
mysql_connect("my database credentials go here");
mysql_select_db("a2275354_gtchose");
$sql=mysql_query("select FName,LName from Test where UserId ='".$_REQUEST['userId']."' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm unsure why the only time i receive a result is when i pass 1 as the userId to the query. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of userid field? moreover, read about http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string if the field type is integer, use `mysql_query("select FName,LName from Test where UserId ='".intval($_REQUEST['userId'])."' ");`

Comment: @Cheery it is of type VarChar, simply because this what im working on now is simply a test for a bigger application where the userId will be a mix of letters and numbers

Comment: echo the $sql statement and tell us the output

Comment: If it is a varchar then check that you do not have spaces in ids. your id should be exactly the same as in $_REQUEST, otherwise nothing will be selected.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee the result comes back as "Resource Manager #9[]" past experience shows me that the Resource manager portion is a result of calling the echo statement, while the [] is my empty array.

Comment: @moneyman232  check your UserId records. If you want to be sure, that the problem is not in php, make `echo mysql_num_rows($sql);` after query. if it is equal to 0, nothing was selected by query. It means that there is no record with UserId you are looking for.

Comment: @Cheery That was the tip that helped me figure out what exactly happened. Turns out that the first part of my test app (which was used to populate my table) somehow inserted the last 3 rows with errors that prevented the php from being correctly queried. Thank you for a great tip

Comment: i meant echo "select FName,LName from Test where UserId ='".$_REQUEST['userId']."' "

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes around userId. Its a numeric field

```
$sql=mysql_query("select FName,LName from Test where UserId =".$_REQUEST['userId']);
```

Comment: sorry let me clarify, from my java file it is passed as a string, not an int type

Comment: It does not matter. Moreover, you are pushing him toward the SQL injection.

Comment: Using zend framework tends to kill your security concerns esp as it takes care of everything. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but you can try this. Adding brackets to your field fname and lname

```
$sql=mysql_query("Select (Fname,LName) from Test where UserId='".$_REQUEST['userID']."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare your array before while loop...so put:

```
$output = array();
```

before `while`, so it should be:

```
$output = array();
$sql=mysql_query(...);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $output[]=$row;
```

Also, as others pointed out, this is vurnerable to sql injection, so use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Also, if your id is numeric, you should really remove that single quote around it...though it doesn't matter it should return results anyway...

Comment: checking my output the result comes back as an empty array " [] "

Comment: Then you don't have any results. Try without WHERE part in your query.

Comment: Tried that...same result unfortunately, it's definitely an error in the scripting, my tests come back with results as intended from phpmyadmin. But something in the php is failing to return the correct result.

Comment: Try without WHERE part in your query... most likely $_REQUEST['userId'] is not valid (empty string, null or something like that)...